# RWD theme 1.9 attributes.phtml

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I cannot find the attributes.phtml in my files. I want to edit how the additional tabs content shows. I don't want it to be in table instead to be the same as the description
tab. How should I edit it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magento rwd theme falls back on the base default theme. So if the attributes.phtml is not in the rwd theme it will be using the one from the base theme. So if you want to edit this I'd  copy it to your themes directory i.e

Copy
{magento_base}app/code/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

To
{magento_base}app/code/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

@see link below for a must read.

[Magento CE 1.9 and EE 1.14 Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide)

Comment: Hi. Yes I already did. I found out the other files is on the other themes :)